# Firebase "Missing required module 'FirebaseFirestoreInternalWrapper'", when i import FirebaseFirestore in my ios app

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, uikit

Everything is ready like firebase, firebase was installed by SDK's. Everything is included like import FirebaseCore , and FirebaseApp.configure(). Maybe I should write in some another context, guess will be better if i send the code.

```
import UIKit
import FirebaseCore


@main class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
        // Override point for customization after application launch.
        FirebaseApp.configure()
        return true
    }

    // MARK: UISceneSession Lifecycle

    func application(_ application: UIApplication, configurationForConnecting connectingSceneSession: UISceneSession, options: UIScene.ConnectionOptions) -> UISceneConfiguration {
        // Called when a new scene session is being created.
        // Use this method to select a configuration to create the new scene with.
        return UISceneConfiguration(name: "Default Configuration", sessionRole: connectingSceneSession.role)
    }

    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didDiscardSceneSessions sceneSessions: Set<UISceneSession>) {
        // Called when the user discards a scene session.
        // If any sessions were discarded while the application was not running, this will be called shortly after application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions.
        // Use this method to release any resources that were specific to the discarded scenes, as they will not return.
    }


}
```

I just need to import this lib, cause of it is a storage, I want to use firebase storage to display list of elements from firebase.

Comment: Try to reproduce this issue within a new app. If it doesn´t persist compare both projects line by line.

Comment: I really dont know what was wrong with it, but i have just created a new app and the firebase server, and it works. Thank you for the help!!!

Answer (score 1):

You should try looking at your project's Build Phases, looking under the section "Link Library with Binaries" and ensure that FirebaseFirestore and FirebaseFirestoreSwift have been added. If not, you can manually add them using the plus button. Oftentimes, packages will not automatically be added here, which has caused me to receive the same error that you did

Answer (score 0):

Add the framework manually in your project settings:

[image]